# Is '+ ((visible && "is-active") || "")' a good practice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm writing fancy login modal and encountered a little confusing problem. I need to toggle modal in React. And thought that this is most elegant way. But is it safe? Or good practice.

```
className={ 'modal ' + ((this.state.showLoginModal && 'is-active') || '') }
```

I expect this not to fail on some browsers.

Comment: No, this is a horrible pattern. Use a proper conditional operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's totally ok to use that syntax, but I would prefer to go with ticks and ternary operators from ES6:

```
className={`modal ${this.state.showLoginModal ? 'is-active' : ''}`}
```

[Explained here.](https://mattferderer.com/using-ternary-operators-in-es6-string-templates)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative suggestion, if you find yourself doing this type of thing all over the place then consider using [classNames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) for a cleaner API

```
// 'is-active' if true, '' if false
classNames({ 
  'is-active': this.state.showLoginModal 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It *currently* works. Then, somewhen, someone wants to invert the logic and swaps both strings:

```
 ((this.state.showLoginModal && '') || 'is-active')
```

And voíla, its broken. I'd prefer a ternary here, as it is easier to understand and more bulletproof:

```
  this.state.showLoginModal ? "is-active" : ""
```

Answer (score 0):

why not simply use ternary which will be more readable and easy to understand

```
className={ 'modal ' + (this.state.showLoginModal ? 'is-active' : '') }
```